# Golang executable build giving error while running inside docker container

Tags: docker, go, dockerfile

I was trying to build an application based on microservice architecture to get some hands-on and also to add it to my resume one of the service is producer-service which i have builded using golang
But when i am trying to use my dockerize image in kubernetes i am getting this error in pod logs

```
./main:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6:version `GLIBC_2.32' not found (required by ./main)
./main:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6:version `GLIBC_2.34' not found(required by ./main
```

This is my dockerfile for that service-

```
# Use an official Go runtime as a parent image
FROM golang:1.20 AS build

# Set the working directory inside the container
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the Go project files into the container
COPY . .

# Build the Go application
RUN go get -u http://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go/kafka && CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build cmd/producer-service/main.go

# Start a new, lightweight imageFROM debian:bullseye-slim
FROM debian:bullseye-slim

# Set the working directory for the final image
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the compiled Go binary from the build image
COPY --from=build /app/main .

# Expose the port your server will listen on
EXPOSE 8080

# Define the command to run your server
CMD ["./main"]
```

I have tried using different base image in the final stage like debian:bookworm as it was having the latest version of [glibc](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianBookworm)

Comment: Try using golang-1.20-bullseye as the build base. You are building in one distribution, running in another.

Comment: Ok this helped me still some other issues to encounter